# Preg match all for extract name of function and parameter

Tags: function, parameters, preg-match-all

I have this string:

```
not(matches(#[Sécurité][Alarme][Mode]#, ["Desarmer",{"action":"Desarmer Sys"}]), result).
```

And I want to extract the name of the function: `not`

And I want to extract the parameters of function, too:

```
matches(#[Sécurité][Alarme][Mode]#, ["Desarmer",{"action":"Desarmer Sys"}])
result
```

I tried with this but it does not work:

```
~[\w]+(?:\w+(\([^()]*+(?:(?1)[^()]*)*+\)))+~u
```

It works fine for the first sentence but, if I recall for function on parameter
"matches(#[Sécurité][Alarme][Mode]#, ["Desarmer",{"action":"Desarmer Sys"}])" I can't obtain the right parameter.

This is a list of all different parameters:

- matches(#[Sécurité][Alarme][Mode]#, ["Desarmer","Desarmer Sys"]),
- #[Sécurité][Alarme][Mode]#,
- "Desarmer",
- ["test11","test-12"],
- {"t1":"test-21","t2":"test22"},
- ["test11","test-12",{"t2":"test21","t2":"test-22"}],
- #test#,
- ["#[Sécurité][Alarme][Mode]#","test12",{"t3":"#[Sécurité][Alarme][Mode]#","t2":"test-22"}]

Answer (score 1):

I think a more careful description of the various elements is in order (in particular to avoid pitfalls like round brackets inside a string), :

```
$pattern = <<<'REGEX'
~
# subpatterns definition

(?(DEFINE)
    (?<dqstring> " [^\\"]*+ (?s: \\ . [^\\"]* )*+ " )
    (?<bcontent> [^()"]*+ (?: \g<dqstring> [^()"]* )*+ )
    (?<rbrackets> \( \g<bcontent> (?: \g<rbrackets> \g<bcontent> )*+ \) )
    (?<pcontent> [^,()"]* (?: (?: \g<dqstring> | \g<rbrackets> ) [^,()"]* )* )
)

# main pattern

    \G [(,] \s* (?<param> \g<pcontent> ) (*:param)
|
    (?<funcName> \w+ ) (*:funcName)
~xu
REGEX;

$str = 'not(matches(#[Sécurité][Alarme][Mode]#, ["Desarmer",{"action":"Desarmer Sys"}]), result)';

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach($matches as $m) {
    $type = $m['MARK'];
    echo "$type:  ", $m[$type], PHP_EOL;
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/Qe1hO)